# Is it beter to use parameterized routes or @Input() when you have the possibility to use both?

Tags: angular

Is it beter to use parameterized routes or `@Input()`?

I have a RecipeList child component that takes an id, it has a parameterized route, so that's one way of getting the id. However, since it's a child component I know that the parent component can also pass it as an `@Input()` property to the child component.

Which of the two is preferable and performance efficient?

In the following scenario I would imagine that `@Input()` is more efficient:

- RecipeListComponent (parent component)
- RecipeComponent (child component)
- RecipeService

**Using @Input() property**

RecipeListComponent (parent):

```
recipes: Recipe[];

constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService)

ngOnInit() {
  this.recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes();
}
```

RecipeListComponent's template (parent):

```
<!-- Passing recipe element to child's @Input() -->
<app-recipe *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" [routerLink]="[recipe.Id]" [recipe]="recipe"></app-recipe>
```

RecipeComponent (child):

```
@Input() recipe: Recipe;

ngOnInit() {

}
```

***vs***

**parameterized routes + service**

RecipeComponent (child):

```
recipe: Recipe;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private recipeService: RecipeService)

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
     this.recipe = this.recipeService.getRecipe(+params['id']);
  })
}
```

RecipeListComponent's template (parent):

```
<!-- We don't pass a property to the child anymore -->
<app-recipe *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" [routerLink]="[recipe.Id]"></app-recipe>
```

RecipeListComponent (parent):

```
recipes: Recipe[];

constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService)

ngOnInit() {
  this.recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes();
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting topic...You could also pass the 'id' by a 'shared' service along several components/modules, or even storing it in the LocalStorage (I guess that this last one would be a bad practice). I am following this question to see what others SOverflow mates think about it.

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero I have updated the question.

Comment: Among all your components, only one should be able to handle the routes (or the state, in case you use ngrx). For this reason we distinguish the smart components, that are the ones that handle the state, and dumb components, that are the ones that receive the state through `@Input`

Comment: My approach is: 1) use route params if the page can/should be accessible to the user just by entering/storing an url, 2) use Input whenever the child is direct descendant of the parent, and 3) use BehaviorSubject/service if the data should be accessible by otherwise not related pages/components. In any case, I prefer - although not always able to control it, since I might work on legacy code sometimes - to have (as @CristianTraina said) smart and dumb components: where dumb ones can only access the data, but all the changes must be done through smart component.

Comment: @lunisolar, `@Input` is to pass variables from parent and child componets, parameterize router is to get the values when you has a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. has no relation :(

Answer (score 0):

You should only send parameters like id, sub id, page no, page size, etc. you should think of these parameter as the base to load page after refresh or from a bookmarked link.

Use case:

1. User of our application saves the link on browser and opens them later.
2. User sends another user the page url and he opens the links

All the other values we should pass to sub components as inputs. To expand on this point, each of our modules will have 2 types of components,. They are

1. Smart components (Folder name Container)
2. Dumb components (Scene name Container)

**Smart components**
As the name suggests, he is the smart one. He knows about the business logic of the module. he knows how to communicate with backend or other services to get informations. He knows how to process these informations.

**Dumb components**
As name suggests, they are only presentation components. The only logic we will write in this components will be presentation logic. These dumb components will receive the data as input from smart components. The only job these dumb components have is to display them.

**Communication between Dumb components to smart components**
There can be instances where the dumb components may need to call a backend service or fetch new values that they may be displaying.  **But dumb components never do business logic. they can only pass the request back to smart components via output**

This may feel like too much work in the beginning. But as our application starts to grow, it will be much difficult to manage the data and create inconsistencies in our application.

**Advantages of this approach.**

1. Ease of debugging
2. Components will be more reusable
3. Loosely coupled elements.